# Live agent chat idle session 10 mins

Tags: liveagent

Can we have an automated end chat feature, if the session is idle for 10 mins, in Live agent configuration of salesforce?

Comment: Did anyone find the answer to this question?

Comment: Nope. I could not :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the button configuration, you can enable "Customer Timeout" including the seconds.

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question. It's little more than saying "yes". I suggest you expand your answer to include more details on how to configure this and exactly where to find these settings so your answer doesn't get deleted in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no declarative way to end a chat after a certain period of time, but you could try using the Salesforce Console Toolkit, there are a few methods for live agent there such as the  endChat() method which you could combine with a timer function using javascript. I haven't tried it myself but that's how I would try to work around that.

Sample code for the **EndChat** method.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/29.0/integration.js"/>
    <a href="#" onClick="testEndChat();return false;">End Chat</a> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testEndChat() {
            //Get the value for 'myChatKey'from the getEngagedChats() or onChatStarted() methods. 
            //These values are for example purposes only
            var chatKey = 'myChatKey';
            sforce.console.chat.endChat(chatKey, endSuccess);
        }

        function endSuccess(result) {
            //Report whether ending the chat was succesful
            if (result.success == true) {
                alert('Ending the chat was successful');
            } else {
                alert('Ending the chat was not successful');
            }
        };
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Please let me know where should I specify the timer? I mean like 10 mins. I am sorry for being an alien here. As I am an admin, I do not have much idea on this. So please help me understand this.

Comment: Somewhere in the Salesforce console embedded in a Visualforce component.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am not able to understand it. I would be really grateful, if you could please let me know how to do it. Please

Comment: Hi Pepefloyd. COuld you please help me to solve this issue? Where should I use this code and what changes I should make in Salesforce console??